# ASP.NET MVC 5 (Visual Studio 2013 Preview) Change Login Url for [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I started playing around with the ASP.NET MVC 5 preview and everything has been going fine so far (I can only recommend it).

However, I wonder where I can set the Login-Url for the Built-In `[Authorize]`-Attribute. I've moved the `AccountController` to a an area, so the path to the Login action is no longer `/Account/Login` but `MyArea/Account/Login`, which is ignored by the `[Authorize]`-Attribute, which in turn means, that whenever one navigates to a controller or action with the attribute set, one is redirected to the wrong path `/Account/Login`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in `web.config` for a section like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Change the `loginUrl` value to point to your updated login page.

Comment: Oh OK, didn't think that this would work - should have tried it. But know when I think of it, the "new" way to do authentication is, of course, still basically Forms authentication. Thank you Matt!

Comment: Thanks this worked. I thought this entire section of the web.config was no longer relevant since Identity came out?

Comment: ASP.NET Identity replaces the MembershipProvider system. Forms Authentication is what tells MVC to show a username/password form vs. Windows Authentication when authentication is required. Forms Authentication uses Identity, or Membership, or anything else to validate the username/password.

Answer (score 16):

When using the new OWIN forms authentication (as opposed to the old ASP.NET forms authentication), this gets set in the `Startup` class. In the default templates, it's in `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` in the `ConfigureAuth` method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
   app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) @slypete

Answer (score 0):

After Trying Many technique in .net MVC 5 in VS2015 I ended up here.

Its was hard to understand but yet very Simple. Whatever we code within Form loginURL was later removed OR replaced by the web.config itself and goes to Account/Login.And this line in the Web.Config does it.

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
```

Comment the line out in web.config and then it won't go to "Account/Login" automatically. I tested in VS2015 and it works like a charm. :)