# ASP.NET MVC Identity: Multiple Login Path and modify the default Login Path in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I  change the default authentication redirection path (/Account/Login) for controllers ?
e.g I got 4 controllers

ABC --> /ABC/Login

BCD --> /BCD/Login

EFG --> /EFG/Login

Home ---> Account/Login

Comment: Are you able to clarify what it is you need? I don't quite understand the question. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Rowan Freeman e.g. If I got 4 controllers (ABC, BCD, EFG e.g.) and all of them are having their own "Login" Action. If the User browse the page /ABC/Details without any Authentication, how we can redirect the user to /ABC/Login, not the default one (/Account/Login).

Comment: You would need to write your own custom `Authorize` attribute. The provided one will only use the single login URL set in the Web.config.

Comment: Couldn't you implement a redirect in the action method of the default authentication redirection path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a custom Authorize attribute, as per Chris Pratt's idea:

```
public class CustomAuthorize:AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
        RouteValueDictionary(new{ controller = controller, action = "Login" }));
    }
}
```

Can be used on your controller like this:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class ABCController : Controller
```

This will redirect an unauthorized client to the Login action on the controller it's trying to access. Remember to put `[AllowAnonymous]` on your Login actions.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `Authorize` attribute and check `IsAuthenticated` inside the `Details` action. if authentication fail, redirect to login action.

Answer (score 1):

as per this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818754/2198830

When using the new OWIN forms authentication (as opposed to the old ASP.NET forms authentication), this gets set in the Startup class. In the default templates, it's in `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` in the ConfigureAuth method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      //here you can change the login url
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
   app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was how to redirect to a _different_ login URL _per controller_. The code you copy/pasted uses a _single_ URL for _all controllers_.