# WebForms authentication as MVC filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

In a migration from WebForms to MVC, some .aspx pages remain. Authentication for these is currently file-based and happens through Web.config. MVC authentication happens by adding an `AuthorizeAttribute` to `GlobalFilters.Filters` and to the controllers/actions as needed.

The Web.config authentication currently looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SignIn.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="10080" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>

<location path="SomePage.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator, BasicUser" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

I would however like to move the WebForms authentication away from Web.config and into an MVC filter that performs a check using a method call. I have been unable to find a single example of this. Is this even possible, and are there any undesired implications of doing it?

I am aware that .aspx files are not handled by the MVC hooks by default.

I am looking for a way to grab all .aspx files regardless of what their code-behind's base class is.

Comment: It depends what kind of authentication your web.config is performing.  What ever it performs can be replicated in code within an `AuthorizeAttribute`.  If you move to using [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity), you needn't worry about having to implement these attributes manually, just add the AuthorizeAttribute globally and go!

Comment: I've added the kind of authentication my Web.config is performing. My current MVC authentication is OWIN-based and I've adapted the old pages to use Claims rather than its existing Custom Principal/Identity. But there is no denial of access or redirection to login when accessing the .aspx pages directly. I'll look at the link you gave me, thanks.

Comment: If your authentication is OWIN based, then you're using ASP.NET Identity already by the sounds of it?  Setting the redirect path is straightforward and if you add the attribute `[Authorize]` to an controller or action and the user is not logged in, it will redirect to the login path specified in your `Startup` Class `LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),` [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27310828/894792)

Comment: I don't have "Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Owin" installed, only "Microsoft.Owin", "Microsoft.Owin.Security", "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" and "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb". Question is: What code must I add where in order to automatically check for authentication on .aspx pages? For MVC, the trick was a GlobalFilter. The most relevant tutorial among the link collection you gave me was [Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project) and it isn't auto.

Comment: Hmmm sorry if I'm side tracking a little bit, but if you're migrating from webforms to MVC why are you using .ASPX pages?  MVC doesn't use .ASPX pages generally... it has .cshtml views and you apply authorisation to Controllers or Actions _on_ the controllers.

Comment: The point of adding a GlobalFilter is for all controllers to have an implicit `[Authorize]` by default. I've got the stuff in Startup.cs that you suggest. This part is working excellently for MVC pages. The old .aspx pages freely grant access once the Web.config properties are no longer there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91849/discussion-between-simon-shine-and-coulton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Global.asax.cs,

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Since MVC does not handle authentication for .aspx pages, do this here.
    AuthController.AuthenticateAspxPage(this.Context);
}
```

and in AuthController, for some type `UserRole`,

```
public const string ErrorRedirectUrl = "~/Auth/Error";

private static readonly IDictionary<string, UserRole[]> _aspxAccessRoles =
    new Dictionary<string, UserRole[]>()
    {
        { "~/SomePage.aspx", new UserRole[] { UserRole.Administrator,
                                              UserRole.BasicUser } },
          ...
    };
```

and then,

```
[NonAction]
public static void AuthenticateAspxPage(HttpContext context)
{
    string ext = context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension;
    string aspxPage = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = context.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

    if ((ext == ".aspx" || ext == ".ashx") && !HasAspxAccess(aspxPage, principal))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(ErrorRedirectUrl);
    }
}

[NonAction]
public static bool HasAspxAccess(string aspxPage, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    if (principal == null || principal.Claims == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    string[] userRoles = principal.Claims
        .Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
        .Select(claim => claim.Value)
        .ToArray();

    UserRole[] accessRoles;

    return _aspxAccessRoles.TryGetValue(aspxPage, out accessRoles)
        && accessRoles.Any(role => userRoles.Contains(role.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't unauthenticated requests rather throw 401 so that Forms module makes 302 out of it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how. It seems [complicated](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/).

Comment: Also, this is more like AuthorizeRequest than AuthenticateRequest. As for 401, just set the response status code. Forms module picks it up at the end of the req lifecycle and makes 302 to the login page.